# Log successful test cases asserts with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

When a pytest test fails, it gives me a nice description of where exactly did the test failed, and with what values exactly.

While this is really great for tests that failed, I would also like to get this report for tests that did NOT fail as well.

for example:

```
    def test_one():
        a =  0
>       assert 0 < a <= 1  # to see what was printed
E       assert 0 < 0 <= 1

test_sample.py:6: AssertionError
--------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------
first
1 failed in 0.12 seconds
```

I would also like to see the value of 'a' if the test did not fail.

for example:

```
    def test_one():
        a = 0.5
>       assert 0 < a <= 1  # to see what was printed
E       assert 0 < 0.5 <= 1

test_sample.py:6: AssertionSuccess
--------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------
first
1 passed in 0.12 seconds
```

Comment: This is a weird requirement. If you're interested in possible values of `a` then why won't you write an appropriate test for that? If it is for debuging purposes then you use appropriate tool (worst case: simple prints). Perhaps I'm missing some context?

Comment: My need is to document each tests with the exact values returned from the functions.
For example, what we do is to check some value of a certain webpage, and we do have some constraints on it, but even if the tests pass, we still want to document for future investigation with what values did the tests pass with (which is later being documented by our CI (Jenkins)).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the value of a in the first test case is 0.
That is since, you have specified,

```
def test_one():
    a=0
```

Also, you should add self, in your arguments, to perform the tests.

When, we test by putting the value of a=0, what happens is when we compare, whether a is less than 1 or, greater than 0. Both, give the result false. Thus, it gives an error.

Whereas, in second case,

```
def test_one():
    a=0.5
```

What happens is when we compare, whether a is less than 1 or, greater than 0.5. Both give the result true. Thus, it gives test passed successfully.

-------- Edited --------
You can add a logger to get logging details.

```
import logging
# Your code
logger = logging.logger()
logging.debug(a)
```

Hope that helped! :)

Comment: I know why my tests fail. This is not the question here, what I wanted to do is to log the value of `a` even when the test passed the same way it does when the test fails.